# Installing PyQt6 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt, pyqt6

When I try to install the PyQt6 library on Raspberry Pi using pip (command "pip install PyQt6") I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
```

Here is the full result:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PyQt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.4.2.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpibnxfxlu
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ahxh_8fa/pyqt6_64f704c0d362442abcae9385cfcd89c0
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5i1i4ta7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5i1i4ta7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5i1i4ta7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 585, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 65, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5i1i4ta7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5i1i4ta7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5i1i4ta7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/e0/e1b592a6253712721612e2e64a323930a724e1f5cf297ed5ec6d6c86dda1/PyQt6-6.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=740244f608fe15ee1d89695c43f31a14caeca41c4f02ac36c86dfba4a5d5813d (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt6/) (requires-python:>=3.6.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpg8vbytn0_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpibnxfxlu Check the logs for full command output
```

I updated pip from version 20.3.4 to 23.0.1. And the console issued the following content:

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
```

Full version:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PyQt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.4.2.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rtbrazp0/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rtbrazp0/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rtbrazp0/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 585, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "project.py", line 65, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rtbrazp0/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rtbrazp0/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rtbrazp0/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

OS: Raspberry Pi 32 bit (Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)), Kernel 5.15.61-v7+, version of Python 3.9.2, hardware Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 and Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Thank you for your help!

UPD:
https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-62-raspberry-pi-raspberry-pi-os

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core reason for `has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'` is  that `qmake` is not in `PATH`. But after adding `qmake` to `PATH` the installation still hangs.

Here is how I got it to work:

#### Install dependencies

```bash
apt install ninja-build libfontconfig1-dev libdbus-1-dev libfreetype6-dev libicu-dev libinput-dev libxkbcommon-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libglib2.0-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libgbm-dev libdrm-dev libx11-dev libxcb1-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxtst-dev libxrandr-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev libxcb-util0-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libxcb-xinput-dev
```

Im not sure if all are needed.

#### Get source

```bash
wget https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.2/6.2.4/submodules/qtbase-everywhere-src-6.2.4.tar.xz
```

#### Build

```bash
tar xf qtbase-everywhere-src-6.2.4.tar.xz
mkdir qtbase-everywhere-src-6.2.4/build
cd qtbase-everywhere-src-6.2.4/build
cmake -G Ninja \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv7l \
-DQT_FEATURE_opengles2=ON \
-DQT_FEATURE_opengles3=ON \
-DQT_FEATURE_kms=ON \
-DQT_AVOID_CMAKE_ARCHIVING_API=ON ..
cmake --build . --parallel 4
```

#### Install Qt6

```bash
cmake --install .
```

#### Get pyqt6 source

```bash
cd
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/01/9e4b91cb0c1023934b1dc654c5bbfc29cbabcbf6092f936b74aee46dd637/PyQt6-6.5.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf PyQt6-6.5.0.tar.gz
```

#### Install build dependencies

Building with pip doesn't work so you need do build with `sip`

```bash
pip install PyQt-builder # will also install sip
```

#### Build

For some reason `-latomic` doesn't get passed properly to g++, so you will have to set `QMAKE_LIBS_LIBATOMIC` manually.

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv7l/bin"
cd PyQt6-6.5.0
sip-wheel --confirm-license --verbose --qmake-setting 'QMAKE_LIBS_LIBATOMIC = -latomic'
```

#### Install pyqt6

```bash
pip install ./PyQt6-6.5.0-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_28_armv7l.whl
```

Comment: The build worked but I cant run any app, since the xcb platform plugin is missing. Also tried it using the eglfs platform plugin which is installed but that didn't work either. Checking the config.summary says that  EGLFS for Raspberry Pi was not enabled. Do you have any idea how to enable that?

Answer (score 1):

I took this approach first, and it worked. I didn't compile Qt6, as you can simply install it by

`sudo apt install qt6-base-dev`

maybe this wasn't existant by the time this thread was created... Then I started with your step 'Install build dependencies'.

But the build time on my raspberry 4 was several hours, I guess round about 3 hours, but I had to leave during the compile time.

I wanted to show 2 other alternatives.

1. Install Qt6 from apt repository:

`sudo apt install python3-pyqt6`

But then PyQt6 goes in the global python directory and not in your python venv environment, so you can't use an app specific venv environment from my understanding.

2. Migrate to PySide6

`pip install PySide6`

This was my final solution, PySide6 has an aarch64 wheel which is raspberry compatible, so install is a piece of cake. And migration also, as PyQt and PySide are nearly compatible, I had only to change the imports and the Slot/Signal class:
https://wiki.qt.io/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt