# Trying to run a PyQt6 program on my raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi4, pyqt6, python-3.11

While running the **init** file, I get an error saying that _ctypes is not installed. My team is assuming that this is something that is installed with PyQt6-Tools.

While trying to install PyQt6-tools with the command `python3.11 -m pip install pyqt6-tools`, i get the following error

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.4.2.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting click (from pyqt6-tools)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/click/click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.4.2 (from pyqt6-tools)
  Using cached PyQt6-6.4.2.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-_9vctyhl/pyqt6_b1d6a39572274ddbae5701391b057d62/project.py", line 65, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 78, in apply_user_defaults
          self._get_qt_configuration()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 493, in _get_qt_configuration
          for line in project.read_command_pipe([self.qmake, '-query']):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_xdna4rw/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 554, in read_command_pipe
          raise UserException(
      sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: See here maybe helpful for you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509805/installing-pyqt6-on-raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509805/installing-pyqt6-on-raspberry-pi)