# DBus PropertiesChanged signal with PySide6/Python doesn't trigger connected slot

Tags: python, qt, pyside, dbus, pyside6

I try to connect the DBus PropertiesChanged Signal with Qt and PySide6/Python, the signal has the following signature:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (STRING interface_name,
                                                   ARRAY of DICT_ENTRY<STRING,VARIANT> changed_properties,
                                                   ARRAY<STRING> invalidated_properties);
```

Concrete I need the signal and PropertiesChanged metadata of the MPRIS standard (https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/, https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mpris-spec/metadata/), the meta data has a dictionary in the propertieschanged dictionary and the inner dictionary has arrays as values on some entries, I can see the data by setting the environment variable "QDBUS_DEBUG": "1" or on a cross check using sdbus:

```
('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player',
{'Metadata': ('a{sv}', {'xesam:albumArtist': ('as', ['Daft Punk', 'Pharrell Williams', 'Nile Rodgers']),
            'mpris:trackid': ('o', '/spotify/track/2Foc5Q5nqNiosCNqttzHof'),
            'xesam:title': ('s', 'Get Lucky (Radio Edit) [feat. Pharrell Williams and Nile Rodgers]'),
            'xesam:album': ('s', 'Get Lucky (Radio Edit) [feat. Pharrell Williams and Nile Rodgers]'),
            'xesam:trackNumber': ('u', 1), 'xesam:discNumber': ('i', 1),
            'mpris:artUrl': ('s', 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2731d5cf960a92bb8b03fc2be7f'),
            'xesam:url': ('s', 'https://open.spotify.com/track/2Foc5Q5nqNiosCNqttzHof'),
            'mpris:length': ('x', 248413000), 'xesam:autoRating': ('d', 0.82),
            'xesam:artist': ('as', ['Daft Punk', 'Pharrell Williams', 'Nile Rodgers'])}),
            'PlaybackStatus': ('s', 'Playing')},
[])
```

I test it currently with the DBus NetworkManager, it is simpler as it has no inner dictionary, but some arrays of objects as value and I can force the signal by enabling and disabling my network connection on Ubuntu, these are 2 example outputs:

```
('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager', {'ActiveConnections': ('ao', ['/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8'])}, [])
('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager', {'State': ('u', 40)}, [])
```

But for neither of the 2 I can't get the connected slot method to run, I also don't get any error. I made a cross check with sdbus and asyncio, with this setup it works. But I can't use the asyncio loop for PySide, as some [required methods](https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup/blob/10941bc37450f2fe99cd3afa4e2331df0439d162/sources/pyside6/PySide6/QtAsyncio/events.py#L318) are not implemented.

I managed to connect to DBus signals with simple data types, but I can't get it to work with PropertiesChanged, whith the dictionaries and arrays.

This is my current code for the NetworkManager service:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide6 import QtDBus, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import QLibraryInfo, qVersion, Slot
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        service = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
        #service="org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotifyd.instance7453"
        path = "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager"
        #path="/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2"
        iface = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
        conn = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()

        #without this, the conn.connect call hangs, seems to be a bug, is already reported and fixed.
        conn.registerObject('/', self)
        
        #bus.connect(service, path, iface, "PropertiesChanged", self, QtCore.SLOT("dbuspropertieschanged(QString,QVariantMap,QStringList)"))    
        #qt.dbus.integration: Could not connect "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" to dbuspropertieschanged(QString,QVariantMap,QStringList)

        conn.connect(service, path, iface, "PropertiesChanged", self, QtCore.SLOT("dbuspropertieschanged(QString, QVariantMap, QVariantList)"))    
        pass

    @Slot(str, dict, list)
    def dbuspropertieschanged(self, arg1:str, arg2:dict, arg3:list) -> None:
        print(arg1)
        print(arg2)
        print(arg3)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Python {}.{}.{} {}'.format(sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1],
                                       sys.version_info[2], sys.platform))
    print(QLibraryInfo.build())
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(qVersion())
    window.resize(800, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup/blob/10941bc37450f2fe99cd3afa4e2331df0439d162/sources/pyside6/PySide6/QtAsyncio/events.py#L318) also says:

> Extending the Type System In order to use one's own type with Qt
> D-Bus, the type has to be declared as a Qt meta-type with the
> Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro and registered with the
> qDBusRegisterMetaType() function. The streaming operators operator>>
> and operator<< will be automatically found by the registration system.

and:

> Warning: You may not use any type that is not on the list above,
> including typedefs to the types listed. This also includes
> QList and QMap<QString,QVariant>.

I saw some C++ examples also using QDBusArgument and overloading the streaming operators, I don't know if this would be the solution, but I also don't know how to do this in Python.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: Until I find somewhere a solution for this, I migrated back to PyQt6. I moved to PySide6, because there ist no ARM64 (Raspberry) package on PyPI for PyQt6, but now I compile it form the source, which takes 2 hours on Raspberry, but DBus handling is much easier with PyQt6....  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509805/installing-pyqt6-on-raspberry-pi